# How to Change tabsize in tabbing-environment?

Tags: indentation, tabbing

I did a lot of Google searches, but I did not found any ideas how to change the tabsize (~~ the indent) for a tab in the tabbing-environment.

I think the indent is set to around 4 characters. But how can I minimize it?

Answer (score 4):

The tabs are determined by where you place them.  When you write `\=` you're settnig the tab.  When you type `\>`, you're moving to the tab.

```
\begin{tabbing}
This is the first line \= of text for tabbing \\
This is \> the second line.
\end{tabbing}
```

Produces

[image]

If you want to put tabs at regular intervals, you can do something like

```
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em}\=\hspace*{3em}\=\hspace*{3em}\=\kill
1 \> 2 \> 3 \>4 \\
\end{tabbing}
```

The `\kill` command essentially lets you set the tabs in the most desirable place but tells LaTeX not to output that line, just save the tabbing positions.

Though this doesn't work entirely as you might expect it to.  For example, if you write:

```
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em}\=\hspace*{3em}\=\hspace*{3em}\=\kill
1 \> 2 \> 3 \>4 \\
Another line \> here.
\end{tabbing}
```

You'll get

[image]

and not

[image]

You should look up the documentation for `tabbing`.  It has a number of nice features.

Comment: This made me rethink my implementation and I got the results I wanted!